# Angular UI-Bootstrap Pagination and Transclude

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm having trouble with ui-bootstrap pagination directive and ng-transclude.

In the following plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RfFdJYD8nEqwzD43TpuY?p=preview the first pagination works well, but when I put the pagination inside one 'Pane' - a custom directive with one header and one div with ng-transclude - it doesn't work.

```
  <div ng-controller="PaginationTranscludeDemoCtrl">

      <pane title="Transclude - This doesn't work">

        <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
        <pre>The selected page no: {{currentPage}}</pre>
        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setPage(3)">Set current page to: 3</button>

      </pane>

  </div>
```

The 'Set Current Page to:3' doesn't work (sometimes works only one time) and the pageChanged always return the same number - see in console.

Anyone know of any issues with UI-Bootstrap Pagination and Transclude?